# Fate based minigames in a historic/fantasy realm?

Tags: game-recommendation, published-adventures, fate, one-shot

I was reading through the [demo chapter](http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/Space%20combat%20demo.pdf) of Diaspora's Fate based sci-fi game and it featured a list of ships and some rules in order to play ship-to-ship combat as a mini-game, without any roleplaying/story involved.

That sounds ideal for trying out the Fate rules and seeing how good they are. Problem is, the person I'd like to join me for such a mini game really dislikes sci-fi stuff.

Does anyone know of a mini-game setup for Fate that is set in a more historic or fantasy world?

Requirements would be:

- Based on the Fate rules
- Needs to come with some information on how to play battles (either small group or large scale is ok)
- Needs to come with a bunch of premades so I don't need to make my own
- Minimal setting information (to explain the premades), but no novels to read
- Less prep-time is better
- If historical, preferably before the age of common gunpowder

The goal is to explore the *rules* of the Fate system in a 1-on-1 setting without needing to create an entire world or getting into roleplaying a complete story. I'd like to save that part for after I figure out whether Fate is as cool as it sounds and I can look for some more players.

Comment: If you're going to check out FATE, you shouldn't avoid roleplaying. FATE makes it easy to play a character and heavily encourages using lateral thinking and roleplaying to advance the story. It's not impossible to play without roleplaying involved, but it will hamper the experience.

Comment: Yes. Demoing "the rules" of Fate without any roleplay around them will be both confusing, and demonstrate that they utterly suck. Fate's system is inseparable from the roleplaying part—it simply does not work without it. Take Diaspora's spaceship battle rules, as an example: they are really, really boring to use when there is no story to make your choices matter.

Comment: Do you care what edition of Fate you learn? (There are a number of very different systems in that family)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fate Toolkit contains rules for squad-based combat and wars which don't require characters. Reading them over, I assume they play similarly to whatever rules Diaspora uses for spaceships.

Also, as @SevenSidedDie notes in the comments, Diaspora has similar rules - if you planned on using Diaspora anyway, you might want to just spring for the whole book.

[Fate Toolkit: Squad-based Action](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/squad-based-action)

[Fate Toolkit: Mass Combat](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/means-war-mass-combat)

Comment: Note that Diaspora's rules contain not just rules for spaceships, but for mass and squad-based action too. These look very similar.